# Can anyone identify this bug please

Tags: species-identification, entomology

We had just gotten a new kitten from a not great home. It was her second night here, and she was laying on my chest when I noticed that where she had been lying on me was really really itchy. When I looked down I thought I was looking at dust, but it was moving and there must have been like 5 or 6 of them. I can barely see it, they just looked like little brown spots and I'm hoping to god its not bed bugs.

It looks like it has antennae and 6 legs maybe I'm really sorry about how blurry the photos are. The YouTube video is easier to see [here (youtube video)](https://youtu.be/U8LbkV3hFz4). I'm not good at identifying insects so please help me.

Thank you!

[image]

[[image]

[image]

Comment: Do they live huge big pimples on you ?
Put the cloth your cat has been on in the freezer overnight first. You can get some "diatoms earth" (I am not sure what the name is in English) as a way to kill a few on your cat before resorting to hardcore chemicals.

Comment: Very hard to say definitively from your photos and video. To help with ID, a location in the world, and some indication of the environment where you got your kitten - urban, rural etc, would be helpful. Bed bugs don't tend to remain on the host animal, so I suspect something more like a tick or a mite.

Comment: Shes only been here for two days, i got welts after the bugs were on my chest and i found a dead adult in the blanket she came home in, im going through the process of heating and freezing every fabric thing i own because im overly paranoid. We live in a smaller town in the north of Vancouver island and its common here, she also came from an apartment which i know had a problem with bugs and rodents etc.

Comment: Not a bed bug. Really grainy video; can't be absolutely sure of anything. If you have any specimens, try to get a higher quality picture. Freeze or put in ethanol one if necessary.

Comment: what you have is most likely some type of tick,the best way to get rid of them is to treat your cat using one of the tic repelling products out there,ask your cat`s vet what the recomended treatment are.some of the products can be used to get rid of fleas,ticks and mites at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

May be rat mite - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornithonyssus_bacoti

When the tropical rat mite bites its host, it causes an inflammatory reaction to its saliva and then pruritic nonspecific dermatitis, known as rat mite dermatitis.

Comment: I agree they look like mites, but a better (more enlarged) photo would help there.  Definitely not ticks and probably not bedbugs, though.